# Adding an ID tag to a post title (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I've been trying for a while to find a way to add an ID tag to a post title by placing a function in a child theme's functions.php file.

I've tried the code below which works well for including an ID for any h1 to h6's that don't have an ID (& leave any that do alone) INSIDE the post content - but I can't find a way to add an ID to the actual displayed post title?

```
function auto_id_headings( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/(\<h[1-6](.*?))\>(.*)(<\/h[1-6]>)/i', function( $matches ) {
        if ( ! stripos( $matches[0], 'id=' ) ) :
            $matches[0] = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ' id="' . sanitize_title( $matches[3] ) . '">' . $matches[3] . $matches[4];
        endif;
        return $matches[0];
    }, $content );

    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'auto_id_headings' );
```

I was thinking it was as simple as changing `the_content` in the "add_filter" part of the code to `the_title` but that hasn't worked! FYI the page I'm trying to do this on is here: https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/reaction-form/

Can anybody help?

I've included a screenshot of the page's chrome developer tools explaining what I'm trying to achieve below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hook the_content return all post content (include HTML), but hook the_title return you value from post_title field (wp_post table).
So if you want to add tag id to id or class DOM element you need make changes in your child theme:
1. copy single.php (or another page template where you need make changes) in your child theme
2. find the place with the_title() function
3. change h1 class (add your function)

Comment: If I use `the_title` instead of `the_content` how can I get it to return the html elements (h1 id=‘ ‘ class=‘ ‘ style=‘ ‘ etc) as that’s the part I want to filter (is that even possible?) - also surely would be better to place the filter in the child theme's functions.php since copying single.php to child theme would not be good for theme updates going forward? - please advise

Comment: if you already make child theme, so the best solution make changes at single.php in child theme, how I told before.. if you used the_content, you can only get text content of title; also update the parent theme after making changes at single.php child theme is safety

Comment: the_title hook return you an only text what you input in the title field in wp-admin